# Highstock charts error: this.labelBBox is undefined line 30

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a web application, with tons of fully functional Highchart graphs.
I am trying to implement Highstock in a graph, but it is giving me a firebug error directly in the Highstock file:

```
this.labelBBox is undefined line 30 of Highstock.js
```

All my libraries are up to date (exactly the same as the demo versions online)
I cannot figure out why I am having this error, here is my code:

```
function generateChart10(id, dataChart, currencies){
    // create the chart
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : id,
            marginLeft: 15,
            borderColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },           
        rangeSelector : {
            enabled: false
        },
        navigator : {
            enabled: false
        },
        scrollbar : {
            enabled: false  
        },

        title : {
            text : ''
        },

        series : [{
            type : 'candlestick',
            name : currencies,
            data : dataChart
        }]
    });
}
```

My dataChart has this value:

[[1336507200000,0.9996,1.0063,0.9989,1.0022],[1336420800000,0.9924,1.0022,0.9924,0.9996],[1336334400000,0.9981,0.9986,0.9921,0.9926],[1336075200000,0.9879,0.9963,0.9861,0.9956],[1335988800000,0.9867,0.9892,0.9828,0.9879],[1335902400000,0.9856,0.9903,0.9849,0.9867],[1335816000000,0.9877,0.9897,0.9832,0.9857],[1335729600000,0.981,0.9894,0.9804,0.9877],[1335470400000,0.9858,0.987,0.98,0.9801],[1335384000000,0.9826,0.9865,0.9805,0.9858]]

Would anyone know why I am having this error ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was just that the order of the timestamps were in reverse (new to old).
So I just reversed the array `dataChart` and that fixed it!